# SimpleCursorAdapter with ContentProvider; ListView empty

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` trying to display data which comes from a content provider. But the `ListView` stays empty. Have been searching for an answer for 3 days.

Here is my code:

**IssuesFragment.java**

```
public class IssuesFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private SimpleCursorAdapter issuesAdapter;
private static final int ISSUES_LOADER = 0;

private static final String[] ISSUES_COLUMNS = {
        DbContract.issues._ID,
        DbContract.issues.ID,
        DbContract.issues.THUMBNAIL,
        DbContract.issues.TEXT
};


public static final int COL_ISSUES__ID = 0;
public static final int COL_ISSUES_ID = 1;
public static final int COL_ISSUES_THUMBNAIL = 2;
public static final int COL_ISSUES_TEXT = 3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public IssuesFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ISSUES_LOADER, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_issues, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.issues_listview);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ISSUES_LOADER, null, this);

    issuesAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.issues_list_item,
                    null,
                    ISSUES_COLUMNS,
                    new int[]{
                            R.id.issues_list__id,
                            R.id.issues_list_id,
                            R.id.issues_list_thumbnail,
                            R.id.issues_list_text,
                    },
                    0
            );
    listView.setAdapter(issuesAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Uri issuesEntry = DbContract.issues.buildIssuesUri();

    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            issuesEntry,
            ISSUES_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    issuesAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    issuesAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

Here are the corresponding Layout files:

**issues_list_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/issues_list__id" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/issues_list_id" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/issues_list_thumbnail" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/issues_list_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_issues.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout 
     ....
    />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/issues_listview"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyListElem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Keine Ausgaben vorhanden." />

</LinearLayout>
```

My cursor gets filled with data. I verified that by printing `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor)` within the `onLoadFinished` Method. But the data doesn't get from there to the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. The element  emptyListElem Textview from fragment_issues.xml was replacing the list element, even though i had

```
View empty = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emptyListElem);
listView.setEmptyView(empty);
```

in my *onCreateView* method which AFAIK should make the emptyListElem show up only if there is no content to fill the list. Seems like i was mistaken. Or maybe i had the code in the wrong place.

edit: i removed the Element emptyListElem and it works now.

Comment: Yes. After i removed emptyListElem the content appeared.